# SQL Server conditional where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following where clause that begins with the following:

```
DECLARE @Birthdate = 1

SELECT ... 
FROM ... 
JOIN ...
WHERE A.organization_id = 1
  AND LEFT(A.[first_name], 3) = LEFT(B.[first_name], 3)
  AND LEFT(A.[last_name], 3) = LEFT(B.[last_name], 3)
```

After this I would like to conditionally execute additional clauses.

For example:

- if `@Birthdate = 1` then add `AND A.[birthdate] = B.[birthdate]`
- otherwise, don't add anything

I've tried the following and none seem to work properly:

Ex 1:

```
 AND (@Birthdate = 1 AND A.[birthdate] = B.[birthdate])
```

Ex 2:

```
AND ((@Birthdate = 1 AND A.[birthdate] = B.[birthdate]) OR 
     (@Birthdate = 0 AND (A.[birthdate] = B.[birthdate] OR 
                          A.[birthdate] <> B.[birthdate])))
```

Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `or` to apply your filter, or to just return all rows when `@Birthdate = 0`

```
SELECT
    ...
FROM
    ...
WHERE
    (
        -- Apply the filter if applicable
        (
            @Birthdate = 1
            and A.[birthdate] = B.[birthdate]
        )
        -- Or return everything
        or @Birthdate <> 1
    )
```

Comment: You're welcome! Any easy way to remember this, is to keep in mind that it all comes down to `true` and `false`. if the predicate evaluates to true for a row that is being checked, then it will get returned. So if you set `@birthdate` to 0, then having a predicate of `@birthdate <> 1` is a perfectly valid way to say "return everything", because it will always evaluate to true.